# Python - Windows - Keep Program On Top Of Another Full Screen Application

Tags: python, windows, fullscreen

Is it possible to have my program running so that it is always on top. Even when there is a full screen application running, such as a game or video?

Comment: What kind of program? Are you using a GUI toolkit, or do you just mean a program running in the windows commandline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make your window topmost, but any program that asks to be topmost after yours will get it, and draw over your window.

It's impossible to make a window that is *always* on top of every other window. In his article, [How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx), Raymond Chen writes,

> We already know that you can't create a window that is always on top,
>   even in the presence of other windows marked always-on-top. An
>   application of the "What if two programs did this?" rule demonstrates
>   that it's not possible, because whatever trick you use to be
>   on-top-of-always-on-top, another program can use the same trick, and
>   now you have two on-top-of-always-on-top windows, and what happens?

However, there is some small hope. He goes on to write,

> The only sane way out is to have the programs coöperate to determine
>   who is in control of the screen at any particular time.

Practically speaking, this is achievable in a few ways:

- Call up the developers of the game program and video program, and ask them to add code to their systems, that check for the presence of your window, and don't take the topmost property if it's there.
- Be the developer of the game program and video program, and add the checking code yourself.
- Be the creator of the operating system all these programs run on, and give exclusive preferential "super-topmost" treatment to your program.